# docker build fails to load .net image

Tags: docker, .net-core

I have a docker file which  has following line of code. It works on an old Linux build machine but doesn't work on a new ubuntu build machine. On new machine it fails with error "net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)".

```js
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0
RUN dotnet restore -s <url> <project path>
RUN dotnet publish <project path> -c Release -o <path>
```

Comment: Can you try to edit the `/etc/hosts` file and commented out the line

`#::1    localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback` ?

Comment: .NET core 2.0 reached end of life on October 1st, 2018. The reason it works on the old machine is probably that the image has been pulled on that machine a long time ago. It's no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

.NET 2.0 is not available anymore because the [EOL is reached](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core).

Try to [migrate your application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) to at least .NET Core 3.1 or even .NET 6.0 (LTS) / 7.0

```xml
/// To .NET Core 3.1
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

```xml
/// To .NET 7
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Docker images can be found [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-aspnet/) for example:

```
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just for testing I had upgraded to .net core 2.2 because another application has net core 2.2 and docker for that app is working file. However when in my app I use FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2 it works but command "RUN dotnet restore" within docker file fails. I guess "RUN dotnet restore" works only for sdk so I think even if I upgrade to net7.0  dotnet restore  won't work.

Comment: Correct you have to use `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0` to build your application and then copy over to a run image like `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0` for a final image [how to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/building-net-docker-images?view=aspnetcore-7.0)